# Access JSON array value with number name

Tags: arrays, json, ibm-cloud, workload-scheduler

We have the following JSON structure

[image]

I am trying to access data array values. I notice value names are numbers and somehow when trying to define the logic, they are not recognized. All the following had errors.

```
series[0].data[0].0
series[0].data[0].0[0]
series[0].data[0]."0"
series[0].data[0].'0'
```

> The error message is "member '0' not found"

(swapping the last part of the logic, same error on every attempt)

Could you please help me figure out if there is a sytanx problem or something else?

This is the first part only non-processed dummy data

```
{
  "request": {
    "command": "dummy",
    "series_id": "dummy"
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "series_id": "dummy",
      "name": "dummy",
      "units": "dummy",
      "f": "W",
      "unitsshort": "dummy",
      "description": "dummy",
      "copyright": "dummy",
      "source": "dummy",
      "start": "19900406",
      "end": "20180803",
      "updated": "2018-08-08T14:01:44-0400",
      "data": [
        [
          "20180803",
          2.104
        ],
        [
          "20180727",
          2.11
        ],
        [
          "20180720",
          2.042
        ],
     ...
```

BTW, I am using IBM Workload Scheduler to access an API to retrieve this data. The tool framewrok let's me specify the JSON Properties I want to get from the results. If I try to get the whole first array value I succeed

```
series[0].data[0]
```

> JSONResult:[20180803, 2.104]

---

UPDATE

Adding screens from IBM Workload Scheduler

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try like this `series[0].data[0][0]`.

Comment: Are you just missing speech marks? If there's an object with an attribute called 1, access it as myObj["1"]. If it's an array and you want the element at index 1; myArr[1].  If you want to iterate through the numerical attributes of an object, you could set a counter and break out of your loop on undefined, accessing your elements as myObj[""+counter] (untested)

Comment: So like... series[0].data[0]["0"]

Comment: @ScottAllen same result as series[0].data[0][0]...  JSONResult:[20180803, 2.104]

Answer (score 0):

As was said in the comments, if you want to get the value `20180803` you should be using `series[0].data[0][0]`. Here is an example:

```js
let theData = {
  "request": {
    "command": "dummy",
    "series_id": "dummy"
  },
  "series": [{
    "series_id": "dummy",
    "name": "dummy",
    "units": "dummy",
    "f": "W",
    "unitsshort": "dummy",
    "description": "dummy",
    "copyright": "dummy",
    "source": "dummy",
    "start": "19900406",
    "end": "20180803",
    "updated": "2018-08-08T14:01:44-0400",
    "data": [
      [
        "20180803",
        2.104
      ],
      [
        "20180727",
        2.11
      ],
      [
        "20180720",
        2.042
      ]
    ]
  }]
}

console.log(theData.series[0].data[0][0])
```

Comment: using `series[0].data[0][0]` do you still get the same error `"member '0' not found"` ? Did you double check the `data` key's value is actually an array of arrays?

Comment: Using that code I get the entire array position ("20180803", 2.104) If you check the logic I've pasted, as far as I understand, series is an array with an unique object, within data property an array (n positions) of arrays (2 positions).